# Office URI - doc opened in read only mode

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-2016

I have a word document that sit in a website in my iis,

When i opening the document with office uri from js like this :

window.open("ms-word:ofe|u|http://WSBJRM:8090/test/abc3.docx"),

the doc opened in word but in read only mode,

that cause that when i save the document it opened as save as,

I want the document will open in editing mode,

My user, iis_iusrs, and the user running the app pool have full permissions to the website and the folder,

When i open the doc directly from folder it opens in editing mode,

Thank you